# Change Codemirror mode on the fly through a select menu

Tags: javascript, codemirror

I am trying to change a codemirror mode on the fly using the methode below, but it is unfortunately not working and your help is welcome

I have a select menu such :

```
<select name="idLanguage" id="select" onChange="selectMode()">
<option value="1">Python</option>
<option value="10">JavaScript</option>
<option value="33">Asterisk dialplan</option>
<option value="34">Clojure</option>
<option value="35">Common Lisp</option>
<option value="36">D</option>
<option value="37">ECL</option>
<option value="38">Go</option>
<option value="39">Haskell</option>
<option value="40">HTML</option>
<option value="41">Jinja2</option>
<option value="42">LiveScript</option>
<option value="43">mIRC</option>
</select>
```

and then I use this javascript method :

```
var modeInput = document.getElementById("select");
function selectMode() {
  var myindex  = modeInput.selectedIndex;
  var modefly = modeInput.options[myindex].text.toLowerCase();
  alert(modefly); // This is giving me the exact mode on the screen
  editor.setOption("mode", modefly);// no change in the mode
  CodeMirror.autoLoadMode(editor, modefly);//no change in the mode
  //editor.refresh();
   }
```

Although the `alert()` is giving the right answer, the mode is not changed

Any idea ?

Thank you

**UPDATE :**

I am loading all the modes in the header (python, javascript etc ..)
I changed the structure of codemirror assets, I have a single directory called `assets` that contain a folder `js` with all the javascripts including codemirror modes so I am thinking that this is no longuer valid

`CodeMirror.modeURL = "../mode/%N/%N.js";`

how should I fix it ?
with the configuration of folders I have right now, even the lazy mode example is not working

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update** I just remembered that my mode changer would never work unless I provided the mime type code mirror expects, not the mode name. i.e. pass it `text/x-markdown` and not `markdown`

I'm using the latest release of codemirror on my site http://pste.me.

Via a select menu, the mode can be changed using:

```
$('#mode').change(function(){
   editor.setOption("mode", $(this).val() );
});
```

Where `editor` is a reference to an `CodeMirror.fromTextArea` object.

I'm not a codemirror expert but I believe the addition mode/autoload methods are no longer used. I'm not having any problem with it auto-loading the needed files, but you could always dynamically build a new script tag and append it to the document `head` before setting the mode.

That's the method we use for the editor themes:

```
// Append the theme styles
var link = document.createElement('link');
link.onload = function(){
    pste.editor.setOption("theme", theme);
};
link.rel = "stylesheet";
link.media = "all";
link.href = INTERFACE_URL+"/codemirror/theme/"+theme+".css";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Comment: Thank you ! In your jquery in the beginning is $('#mode') refer to the name of your list ?

Comment: It's just the ID of the `select` field for changing the mode. I just thought of one important thing... updating answer now

Comment: hmm, it still not working for me. Did you keep the same structure as codemirror ? I am thining about that since I put all js in the same asset folder

Comment: I am still having this when I debug with firefox : [01:47:37.831] TypeError: editor.setOption is not a function

Comment: That's just a variable you need to set yourself. Like `var editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(...)`

Comment: I think at some point editor becomes unknown. where should I use  editor.setOption("mode", $(this).val() ); when I create the editor ?

Comment: I'm guessing you have problems with variable scope, once you've created the codemirror instance, `editor` should not lose it unless it's defined in a different function from your change event. Checkout this code, it would allow everything to work: http://pste.me/tbkXy/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40873/discussion-between-rad-and-botskonet)

Comment: Problem Solved you were right I was trying to change the editor out of the function ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

This solution is working for me, hope you find this useful.

In html file load these scripts

```
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="/node_modules/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"
></script>
<script
  src="/node_modules/codemirror/addon/mode/loadmode.js"
  defer
></script>
```

And int your script.js

```
CodeMirror.modeURL = "/node_modules/codemirror/mode/%N/%N.js";
let editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.querySelector("textarea"), {
  lineNumbers: true,
  value: "",
  matchBrackets: true,
  autoCloseBrackets: true,
});

var modeInput = document.getElementById("select");
function selectMode() {
  var myindex  = modeInput.selectedIndex;
  var modefly = modeInput.options[myindex].text.toLowerCase();
  alert(modefly); 
  //Make sure to use valid MIME type according to the selected input
  editor.setOption("mode", modefly);
  CodeMirror.autoLoadMode(editor, modefly);
  //editor.refresh();
}
```